# (find: *.png: No such file or directory) terminal

Tags: terminal

I am trying to do some batch processing in terminal with texturePacker. The creator of texturePacker said that this is the way that you batch convert a directory of .pngs to .pvr.ccz.

```
find <directoryname> -name \*.png | sed 's/\.png//g' | \
    xargs -I % -n 1 TexturePacker %.png \
        --sheet %.pvr.ccz \
        --data dummy.plist \
        --algorithm Basic \
        --allow-free-size \
        --no-trim \
        --opt RGBA4444 \
        --dither-fs
```

But I keep getting this output in the terminal.
(find: *.png: No such file or directory)
Does anyone know why it would be saying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify the name of the directory containing the files: where the placeholder `<directoryname>` is? Is there at least one file ending in .png in that directory?

Try with the first part of the command:

```
find <directoryname> -name \*.png
```

to see if you get the list of files.

Comment: I did replace it with the correct directory and all of the files in that directory are named sequentially frame0.png frame1.png etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're not inputting the directory properly. The command you enter in should be something like: `find /Users/me/mydir/ -name \*.png […]`, with no angled brackets, and if you have any spaces in the directory path, be sure to put it in quotes, like so: `'/Users/me/my directory/'`.

It's also worth noting that the command will act on any PNGs not just within the directory you give it, but also any subdirectories.

An alternate (and slightly more concise) version that just acts on the *current* directory would be:

```
for f in *.png; do TexturePacker "$f" --sheet ${f%.*}.pvr.ccz --data dummy.plist --algorithm Basic --allow-free-size --no-trim --opt RGBA4444 --dither-fs; done
```

Navigate to whatever directory you want in Terminal (easiest way is to type `cd`, drag the folder onto the Terminal window and hit enter), then run that command.